# List within dictionary to a list to represent nodes and edges

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this input:

```
data = {'A': [('B', 7), ('D', 5)], 
    'B': [('C', 8), ('D', 9), ('E', 7)],
    'C': [('E', 5)], 'D': [('E', 15), ('F', 6)]
    'E':[('F', 8), ('G', 9)], 
    'F':[('G', 11)]
}
```

And I´m trying to convert it to:

```
[ ("A", "B", 7), ("A", "D", 5),
  ("B", "C", 8), ("B", "D", 9), ("B", "E", 7),
  ("C", "E", 5),
  ("D", "E", 15), ("D", "F", 6),
  ("E", "F", 8), ("E", "G", 9),
  ("F", "G", 11)]
```

I can't seem to make it work in this exact manner.

Thanks.

Comment: `[(k,) + e for k, v in data.items() for e in v]`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the dict and add the key to the tuple by using `('A',)+('B', 7)`

```
>>> [(k,)+i for k,v in data.items() for i in v]
[('A', 'B', 7), ('A', 'D', 5), ('C', 'E', 5), ('B', 'C', 8), ('B', 'D', 9), ('B', 'E', 7), ('E', 'F', 8), ('E', 'G', 9), ('D', 'E', 15), ('D', 'F', 6), ('F', 'G', 11)]
```